# Read excel autofilter with python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, filter, xlwings

I'd like to read the autofilter rules from an excel sheet in python.

Suppose this kind of input:
[original input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1OLI7.png)

then I filter with excel autofilter one column, for example:
[filtered input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QhT3A.png)

Is there a way to retrieve the applied autofilter rule in python?

Currently the only option I know, it is to set the autofilter via xlwings:

```
import xlwings as xw

# Open the workbook
workbook = xw.Book(r"C:\Users\Desktop\Example.xlsx")

# Set Autofilter
workbook.sheets[0].api.Range("A1:D4").AutoFilter(4,"Yes")
```

but does it exist the "inverse" function?

It could be fine also with other way like pandas, openpyxl, xlsxwriter and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Xlwings you should be able to duplicate what VBA can do so it's usually the better for this type of query.
You should be able to show the Filter set from Criteria1 as shown below;

```
import xlwings as xw

# Open the workbook
workbook = xw.Book(r"C:\Users\Desktop\Example.xlsx")

# Set Autofilter
workbook.sheets[0].api.Range("A1:D4").AutoFilter(4,"Yes")

for count, item in enumerate(workbook.sheets[0].api.AutoFilter.Filters,1):
    if item.On:
        print(f'{count}, {item.Criteria1}')
```

Output would be

```
4, =Yes
```